# How do I get MPN?

Tags: c#, ebay-api

While playing around with eBay .NET SDK, I ran into an issue. I couldn't find some fields I heeded to, such as `EAN, Model, Brand, ASIN` and especially `MPN`.

A class I use as an info class is `eBay.Service.Core.Soap.ItemType`. To get the information about a product I do

```
GetItemCall call = new GetItemCall(_context);
call .DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);
item = apicall.GetItem(itemID.ToString());
```

How can I get these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html#Response.Item.ProductListingDetails.BrandMPN ?

Comment: Well, maybe. For some reason it's null. It's pretty weird.

Comment: Is it possible to uniquely identify a product by MPN? Can I use instead of ItemID?

Comment: No as far as I know, but my usage of the SDK has been minimal... My understanding is that MPN may not even be provided by the person listing the item, which I'm guessing is why it's null for you.

Comment: This also doesn't appear to work for the Java SDK -- getProductListingDetails() returns null. Chiming in because it supports jawanam's comment.